# Euler $\phi$ function is equivalent to the number of elements of $F$ of order $d$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Dummit & Foote 9.5.6: Let $G$ be a finite subgroup of order $n$ of the multiplicative group $F^\times$ of nonzero elements of the field $F$. Let $\phi$ denote Euler's $\phi$-function and let $\psi(d)$ denote the number of elements of $F$ of order $d$. Prove that $\phi(d)=\psi(d)$ for every divisor $d$ of $n$.

I have looked up this question and I see everyone deducing that $F$ is cyclic but my problem doesn't have that. How would I approach it?

Comment: I copied this question from Dummit & Foote Abstract Algebra book

Comment: Oops didn't see you stated $G$ has order $n$.

Comment: It's okay. I happens to me all the time

Comment: Also for who has voted to close this problem, can you please explain why it should be closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finite subgroups of multiplicative groups of fields are cyclic.

to see this let $G$ be such a group and let $m$ be the least common multiple of the orders of all elements of $G$. Notice the polynomial $x^{m}$ has at least $|G|$ roots because every element of $G$ is a root. It follows that $m$ must be at least $|G|$, and for abelian groups this imples the group is cyclic, this can be easily proved with the fundamental theorem for finite abelian groups.